# Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

[Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.[Main.urls[Views.py[Urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QrSW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q88iG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPxwl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KYhw.png)

## NoReverseMatch at /user/signup/

```
Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Request Method:POSTRequest URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/signup/Django Version:4.1.4Exception Type:NoReverseMatchException Value:Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.Exception Location:C:\Users\JOSHI\OneDrive\Desktop\Watch Store\Venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 828, in _reverse_with_prefixRaised during:User.views.signupPython Executable:C:\Users\JOSHI\OneDrive\Desktop\Watch Store\Venv\scripts\python.exePython Version:3.9.0Python Path:['C:\\Users\\JOSHI\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Watch Store\\Online_Shop', 'C:\\Users\\JOSHI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Users\\JOSHI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\JOSHI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\JOSHI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39', 'C:\\Users\\JOSHI\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Watch Store\\Venv', 'C:\\Users\\JOSHI\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Watch Store\\Venv\\lib\\site-packages']Server time:Sat, 31 Dec 2022 06:39:18 +0000

Comment: Its impossible to really help you without knowing how your app is built up. But a quick guess on my side is that the browser is trying to access an API that does not exist in your Django App. Did you maybe forget to set the URL?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.